Water In Window Sills
We have water coming in the bottom sills on the lakeside windows.
Below is the process - What is wrong with this?
There is damage to the drywall after rain.
The water comes down to the basement after rain and after lightly spraying above the window on the siding.
The water is going behind the siding and running down to the basement -  looks to be under the bottom sill plate on the cement floor.
The roof edge vent was removed and replaced with flashing as we thought this was the source of the water.
After the roof vent was removed and replaced with flashing we spray lightly above the windows on the siding the water comes through the sill under the windows.
The windows / foam / siding were installed this way from what I show in the pictures:
Typar
Was put on the house and taped.
Windows
The 2x4 build out frame was nailed around the window openings on top of the Typar.
The windows were installed nailing the nailing flange onto the 2x4.
The windows are not screwed into the frame on the inside.
3 inches of Resisto tape (6 inch piece cut in half) was taped over the nailing flange / side of brick mould and 2x4 and not attached to the Typar on the top / bottom / and sides of windows.
Our plans called for 1 inch foam on the outside of the home.
Due to the 2x4 outside build out, the inside window factory build outs were taken out and replaced with poplar wood build outs and then went with 1.5 inch foam to meet the 2x4 outisde.
Soffit Install
The soffit was installed into the roof trusses with a gap between the OSB and the mono pitch roof line.
Foam Install
Aluminum flashing was caulked and fed into the soffit J channel to try to seal the gap between soffit and open cavity and nailed to the outside of foam.
The Resisto tape on the 2x4 was taped with Tuck tape to the Typar and all 4 sides of the windows to try to connect the Resisto to the Typar.
The foam was nailed to the wall to meet the 2x4 build out.
The foam was taped only on the lakeside.
The window drip caps were nailed through the foam above the windows and the ends are inside the J trim.
Siding Install
The siding at the bottom of the lakeside was nailed with 2 1/2" nails on the board and batten until switched to 3" nails partial way up.
The rain came in the windows after the foam install.
The rain came in the windows after the siding install.
The rain / sprayed hose water comes in after the siding install.
Siding was taken off and foam cut away to find water between the foam and the Typar.
